# Submitting form via Ajax to PHP backend returning an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a form that asks a user for a **name**, **address**, **amount1**, **amount2** and a **comment**.

The radios are different values for amount1 and amount2.

When I submit my form my variable `$rate_error` returns **"you must enter a rating comment";** even though it is not blank.

Could my radio inputs be the problem?

Am I assigning the `amount1` variable wrong?

I need the value of the variable to change when the users selects different amounts.

## HTML

```
 <form id='main-rate' method="POST">
     <input type="search" name="address" id="geocomplete"  placeholder="Type in an address"/>
     <input type="text"  name='landlord_name id="name" '/>

     <input type="radio" name="amount1" id="amount1" value="2">
     <label for"amount1">2<label>
     <input type="radio" name="amount1" id="amount1" value="4">
     <label for"amount1">4<label>
     <input type="radio" name="amount1" id="amount1" value="6">
     <label for"amount1">6<label>
     <input type="radio" name="amount1" id="amount1" value="8">
     <label for"amount1">8<label>
     <input type="radio" name="amount1" id="amount1" value="10">
     <label for"amount1">10<label>

     <input type="radio" name="amount2" id="amount2" value="2">
     <label for"amount2">2<label>
     <input type="radio" name="amount2" id="amount2" value="4">
     <label for"amount2">4<label>
     <input type="radio" name="amount2" id="amount2" value="6">
     <label for"amount2">6<label>
     <input type="radio" name="amount2" id="amount2" value="8">
     <label for"amount2">8<label>
     <input type="radio" name="amount2" id="amount2" value="10">
     <label for"amount2">10<label>

     <textarea  id="comment" name="comment" required="required">
     </textarea>
     <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

## JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("#main-rate").submit(function()
    {


        var address = $('#geocomplete').val();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var comment = $('#comment').val();  

     var amount1 = document.getElementsByName('amount1');
       for (var i = amount1.length; i--;) {
           amount1[i].onchange = function() {

                 amount1 = this.value;
                 console.log(amount1);
             }
         }
    var amount2 = document.getElementsByName('amount2');
       for (var i = amount2.length; i--;) {
           amount2[i].onchange = function() {

                 amount1 = this.value;
                 console.log(amount2);
             }
         }




        var dataString =  name  + address  + amount1 +  amount2 +  comment;

        if (name == '' || address == '' || amount1 == '' || amount2 == '' || comment == '')
        {
            console.log("Please Fill All Fields");
        } else
        {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "path/to/url",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result)
                {
                   console.log(result);

                    $('rate-section').html(
                        '<div><h1>THANKS FOR RATING!</h1></div>'
                     );


                    return false;


                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

## PHP

```
 $rate_error = 0;

 if (isset($comment) && $comment != '') {


        if (!$address_id && !$address) {
            $rate_error = "must enter an address";
        }

        //if not logged in and creating new user
        if (!$SESSION->logged_in()) {
            $User = new USER();

            $rate_error = $User->createUser($username_entered, $email_entered, $pass_1, $pass_2, $fb_user, $g_user, $g_token, 1);
        }
        if (!$rate_error && !$SESSION->user_id()) {
            $rate_error = "error - you must create an account before rating a landlord";
        }


        if (!$comment) {
            $rate_error = "you cannot leave a blank review";
        }
        if (!$landlord_id && !$landlord_name) {
            $rate_error = "you must enter a landlord name";
        }
    } else {
        $rate_error = "you must enter a rating comment";
    }

 if (($landlord_name || $landlord_id) && $rate_error==0) {

  //query to database

  $success = 1;

 }

if ($success){
        $resultArray = array("success"=>1);
        $resultArray['landlord'] = $current_landlord;
    } else {
        $resultArray = array("success"=>0,
            "rate_error"=>$rate_error);
    }
```

## Update

Made some changes to my javascript but now receiving a 500 internal error.

```
    $("#main-rate").submit(function()
        {
             var address = $('#geocomplete').val();
             var name = $("input[name='landlord_name']").val();
             var amount1 = $("input[name='amount1']").val();
             var amount2 = $("input[name='amount2']").val();         
             var amount3 = $("input[name='amount3']").val();         
             var amount4 = $("input[name='amount4']").val();
             var amount5 = $("input[name='amount5']").val();
             var amount6 = $("input[name='amount6']").val();
             var amount7 = $("input[name='amount7']").val();
             var comment = $('#comment').val();                                

             var dataString = {
             name: name,
             address: address,
             amount1: amount1,
             amount2: amount2,
             amount3: amount3,
             amount4: amount4,
             amount5: amount5,
             amount6: amount6,
             amount7: amount7,
             comment: comment

            }


            if (dataString.name == '' || dataString.address == '' || dataString.amount1 == '' || dataString.amount2 == '' || dataString.amount3 == '' || dataString.amount4 == '' || dataString.amount5 == '' || dataString.amount6 == '' || dataString.amount7 == '' || dataString.comment == '')
            {
                console.log("Please Fill All Fields");
            }  else
        {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "path/to/url",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result)
                {
                   console.log(result);

                    $('rate-section').html(
                        '<div><h1>THANKS FOR RATING!</h1></div>'
                     );


                    return false;


                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The data passed through ajax should be either `{name : 'value'}` or `name=value&name2=value2` format

Comment: if you press f12 to open developer tools (in some browsers) and go to the network tab, you can see everything that your form passes.  It's helpful to debug why you aren't picking up certain values

Comment: You could use `.serialize()` to get the data in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

As @ShaunakD points out, you're not sending your data to the server correctly. If all your inputs are filled out with the letter 'a' it will still submit but the PHP is receiving 'aaaaa' (well, not technically, given the radios and amount1&2 assignment issue below) without any indication of what variables are being passed.

I suggest his first approach which would change your dataString assignment line to:

```
 var dataString = {
   name: name,
   address: address,
   amount1: amount1,
   amount2: amount2,
   comment: comment
 };
```

You're current implementation will have issues with retrieving values for amount1 and amount2. You're assigning the event for onchange in the submit function. You should first remove the id attributes for each radio input and replace their assignment of values (and more simply) with:

```
 var amount1 = $("input[name='amount1']").val();
 var amount2 = $("input[name='amount2']").val();
```

EDIT: To give more context to my 1st comment below:

```
 $("#main-rate").submit(function()
 {


    var address = $('#geocomplete').val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var comment = $('#comment').val();  
    var amount1 = $('input[name="amount1"]').val();
    var amount2 = $('input[name="amount2"]').val();

   //Remove this entirely
   /*
   var amount1 = document.getElementsByName('amount1');
   for (var i = amount1.length; i--;) {
       amount1[i].onchange = function() {

             amount1 = this.value;
             console.log(amount1);
         }
     }
   var amount2 = document.getElementsByName('amount2');
   for (var i = amount2.length; i--;) {
       amount2[i].onchange = function() {

             amount1 = this.value;
             console.log(amount2);
         }
   }
   */
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Steve, So should i move the .onchage function outside of the submit event along with the new variable expression "`var amount1 = $("input[name='amount1']").val();`" ?

Comment: I can't see any purpose to the looping of the onchange event handling.  It's going a long way to do what can simply be done with one line, sans looping and onchange event handling. Put simply, remove and replace your var amount1&2 assignments and looping onchange with my suggestion and let me know if you're still having issues with it. Cheers!

Comment: This way does make more sense. It is submitting now but im getting a status 500 internal error from the server.

Comment: Where are you seeing the 500 error? In the dev tools console? Is 'path/to/url' functioning? Your PHP code also doesn't appear to be returning/printing anything to the response, just setting variables that don't appear to get used anywhere.

Comment: Yes it says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: the php up top are the conditions i use to query the database but the path i am using returns `echo json_encode($resultArray);`

Comment: Do you get an error when you request the php in the browser without sending anything? Have you tried removing all/parts of the PHP code to isolate where the error is occurring? Do you have access to error logs? Depending on how you have your server configured, it could be any number of issues. This **might** be helpful: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/http-error-500-internal-server-for-php-pages-and-solution.html

Comment: When i submit without any input i get my `console.log('Please fill in all fields');` Let me try breaking the php to see if i get a different error.